# ¿Como puedo crear una variable de una consulta a Mysql en PHP, para después enviarla en una función con POST?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

El código que intenté es el siguiente:

```
    //index.php

    <?php
    include(conexiones.php)
    $resultado = canecta->query("SELECT titulo, texto FROM db WHERE id = 'libros'");
    $variable1 = $resultado; 
    ?>

    <script>
    function mandaVar(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    chec = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    chec = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    chec.onreadystatechange = ve1;
    chec.open('POST', 'ejecuta.php', true);
    chec.send("pasa=<?php echo $variable1; ?>");

    function ve1(){
    if(chec.readyState == 4){
    if(chec.status == 200){
    texto = document.getElementByid("carga");
    texto.innerHTML = chec.tesponseText;
    }}}}
    </script>

    //ejecuta.php 

    $variable2 = $_POST["pasa"];
    while($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($variable2)){
    $titulo = $filas['titulo'];
    $texto = $filas['texto'];
    echo $titulo;
    echo $texto;
    }
```

Esto no me funciono. ¿De que forma puedo pasar esta variable para no generar otra conexión a mysql y hacerla hasta que le dan click en el botón que activa la función? Ya que también carga en la misma pagina como lo pueden ver.

Como otra opción: Se me ocurría guardarlo en un array multidimensional y en el otro php hacer un while para obtener la información, pero no he podido hacer bien el arreglo con:

```
    <?php
    $resultado = canecta->query("SELECT titulo, texto FROM db WHERE id = 'libros'");
    while($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $array = array($filas);
    $print_r(array);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: entiendo que tu consulta devuelve una única fila no? o esperas mas resultados y enviarlos todos por método post?

Comment: La pregunta y el código son confusos. ¿Podrías explicar lo que quieres lograr independientemente del código? Veo que haces uso de Ajax mezclado con código PHP. Lo suyo sería, desde Ajax mandar al servidor el dato que necesites (por ejemplo el ID), usar ese dato para ejecutar la consulta en el servidor y devolver la respuesta de nuevo a Ajax. ¿Es más o menos eso lo que quieres? ¿Por qué entonces intentas usar en Ajax una variable que está en el contexto del servidor?

Comment: @mourazo, gracias. No, es un While, y lo que quiero pasar es la consulta completa ya sea en una variable o en una variable con un array multidimensional. Un único dato si lo he pasado haciendo la consulta y obteniéndolo con fetch_assoc, lo pongo en un $var = $filas[titulo]; y lo envío con post al activar la función.

Comment: @A. Cedano, gracias. Lo que quiero hacer es no generar otra conexión a MySQL al cargar el ejecuta.php que carga en index cuando se activa la función. Me gustaría tener la consulta y al cargar el ejecuta.php solo pasar los datos para que los muestre. Lo más sencillo sería tener el ejecuta.php e la misma página index.php pero por varias razones de estructura, diseño y rapidez, lo quiero cargar con ajax después, pero que los datos los cargue desde la entrada al index.

Comment: Sigo sin entender. Quizá sea esto lo que te tiene confundido: *Lo más sencillo sería tener el ejecuta.php e la misma página index.php*, porque precisamente lo más sencillo no es eso (si el contexto es el que creo). Imaginemos que de entrada en `index.php` cargas una lista con unos pocos datos sacados de la base de datos (por ejemplo ID, nombre, apellido) y luego, de una fila cualquiera quieres obtener más datos (dirección, fecha de nacimiento, nombre de los padres, sueldo, etc). Lo suyo sería 1. tomar de `index.php`  el ID seleccionado; 2. pasar ese ID a `ejecuta.php` vía Ajax; 3. obtener ...

Comment: ... en `ejecuta.php` los datos propios a ese ID y devolverlos a `index.php` para mostrarlos. Ese es un escenario típico de Ajax, con un archivo intermedio (`ejecuta.php`)  en este este caso, que sirve como pasarela para llevar y traer datos entre cliente y servidor. Un escenario más simple sería precargar todo en una sola llamada (esto es factible si son pocas filas/columnas) y guardar todo en atributos data en el cliente y mostrarlos de forma dinámica. Sea como sea, el principal problema creo yo es que no te queda claro como funciona Ajax y/o que el problema no está planteado con claridad.

Comment: @A. Cedano Ok, me gustaría pasar la consulta que muestro, en una variable ¿se puede? Para que en ejecuta.php poder hacer el while como lo marcó en el “ejemplo” y no hacer una conexión más a mysql. O pasar los datos de las columnas que se obtienen con while para así mostrar la info en ejecuta.php

Comment: Sí, en ejecuta puedes leer todas las filas de la consulta, para ello lo habitual es usar un bucle `while` obtener los datos mediante `fetch_assoc` e irlos metiendo en un array, luego, fuera del `while`  haces un `echo json_encode($elArray);`, donde `$elArray` serían todos los datos que fuiste llenando el `while`. Así, el cliente recibirá como respuesta de la petición Ajax todos los datos que obtuviste en la consulta. OJO, he recomendando responder con `json_encode` porque es la forma habitual y te manda los datos estructurados. Pero debes ajustar la petición Ajax indicando dataType o parsear.

Comment: Has pensado en utilizar sessiones para mantener la persistencia de los datos entre las 2 peticiones?

Comment: @Xerif ¿Te refieres a session_start?

Comment: @A Cedano intentaré esto que me dices, aunque me gustaría encontrar la forma de llevarme la consulta a ejecuta.php para poder ahí hacer el while. Muchas gracias por la información.